# Build.gradle could not resolve symbol.Emulator won't start because of that

Tags: java, android, android-studio, build.gradle

Gradle 'MyApplication' project refresh failed:
         Build script error, unsupported Gradle DSL method found: 'signingConfigs()'!
         Possible causes could be:
         - you are using Gradle version where the method is absent 
         - you didn't apply Gradle plugin which provides the method
         - or there is a mistake in a build script

This is what my event log is writing.Please help me!!What i should to do
Here is a code:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
}
}


allprojects {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
}
 apply plugin: "android"
 android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"
}

signingConfigs {

    release {

        storeFile file('android.keystore')
        storePassword "pwd"
        keyAlias "alias"
        keyPassword "pwd"
    }
}

buildTypes {

    release {

        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

P.S. After i applied code starting from "apply plugin:'android'".So,when i focus with mouse to this code it states"Could not resolve symbol "signingConfig""

Answer (score 0):

your `signingConfigs` and `buildTypes` must be inside `android` tag element.

after making the changes your **`build.gradle`** file will be as shown below :

```
 buildscript {
   repositories {
     mavenCentral()
   }
   dependencies {
     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
   }
 }
 allprojects {
   repositories {
     mavenCentral()
   }
 }

 apply plugin: "android"
 android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
      minSdkVersion 8
      targetSdkVersion 19       
    }

    signingConfigs {
      release {
        storeFile file('android.keystore')
        storePassword "pwd"
        keyAlias "alias"
        keyPassword "pwd"
      }
    }
    buildTypes {
      release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: i did the same as you write,but,event log showed this one:Gradle 'MyApplication' project refresh failed:
         Main Manifest missing from C:\Users\ww\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

The error message "Main manifest missing from..." means that it's looking for an Android project in a given location and it's not finding one. In this case, it's the top-level build file, which is the one you've posted in your question: It now has an `apply plugin: "android"` statement, and it's expecting to see an Android project there. But there's no project there; it's inside your application module, which is a directory level lower.

This file isn't the one where the signing information should go; it belongs in your app module's build file instead. Restore your top-level build file to its normal state:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
         mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

And put the signing information inside the `android` block of your app's **build.gradle** file:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    ...
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file('android.keystore')
            storePassword "pwd"
            keyAlias "alias"
            keyPassword "pwd"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}
```

What's more, consider upgrading to a later version of Android Studio. The one you're running is quite old.